# Como referenciar um desvio padrão no PySpark?

Tags: python, spark

boa tarde!

Eu já pesquisei bastante e não estou conseguindo encontrar uma forma de solucionar isso.
Eu tenho um df sobre ações (meu df tem dados de nome, data, abertura, máxima, mínima, fechamento e volume). Quero descobrir qual ação teve o maior desvio padrão. Eu fiz o seguinte:

```
df.agg({'fechamento': 'stddev'}).show()
```

Isso me trouxe o resultado do desvio padrão da coluna de fechamento, porém eu quero saber qual foi a empresa que teve o maior desvio padrão. Não estou sabendo como resolver isso. Tentei outras coisas também (vou deixar abaixo), mas tudo dá no mesmo lugar.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import stddev
df.select(stddev('fechamento')).collect()
```

Tentei também dessa forma:

```
df.agg({'fechamento':'stddev_pop'}).collect()
```

Como eu referencio a qual empresa o maior desvio padrão pertence? Estou bastante perdida.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Muito obrigada!

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

#Criando um dataframe com alguns exemplos:
data  = [
    ('XPTO11','21/02/2022',14.91,14.99,14.84,14.92,'14.49M'),
    ('MERD4','21/02/2022',8.32,8.55,8.30,8.34,'7.93M'),
    ('MITO3','21/02/2022',78.30,78.42,78.22,78.34,'43.02M'),
    ('XPTO11','22/02/2022',14.96,15.05,14.02,14.02,'14.43M'),
    ('MERD4','22/02/2022',8.23,8.99,8.22,8.90,'7.90M'),
    ('MITO3','22/02/2022',78.99,79.42,78.99,78.98,'42.16M'),
    ('XPTO11','23/02/2022',14.91,14.99,14.84,14.92,'14.49M'),
    ('MERD4','23/02/2022',8.30,8.50,8.26,8.49,'7.76M'),
    ('MITO3','23/02/2022',78.31,78.33,78.00,78.01,'49.33M')
  ]
    
schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("nome",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("data",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("abertura",DoubleType(),True), \
    StructField("máxima", DoubleType(), True), \
    StructField("mínima", DoubleType(), True), \
    StructField("fechamento", DoubleType(), True), \
    StructField("volume", StringType(), True)
  ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema).withColumn('data', F.to_date('data', 'd/M/y'))

#Usando uma Window Function para particionar o DF pelo código da ação:
w = W.partitionBy('nome')

#Adicionando uma coluna com o desvio padrão calculado na window function:
df = df.withColumn('desvio_padrão', F.stddev('fechamento').over(w))

df.show()
```

Output:

```
+------+----------+--------+------+------+----------+------+-------------------+
|  nome|      data|abertura|máxima|mínima|fechamento|volume|      desvio_padrão|
+------+----------+--------+------+------+----------+------+-------------------+
| MERD4|2022-02-21|    8.32|  8.55|   8.3|      8.34| 7.93M|0.28988503468329224|
| MERD4|2022-02-22|    8.23|  8.99|  8.22|       8.9| 7.90M|0.28988503468329224|
| MERD4|2022-02-23|     8.3|   8.5|  8.26|      8.49| 7.76M|0.28988503468329224|
| MITO3|2022-02-21|    78.3| 78.42| 78.22|     78.34|43.02M| 0.4931869152089599|
| MITO3|2022-02-22|   78.99| 79.42| 78.99|     78.98|42.16M| 0.4931869152089599|
| MITO3|2022-02-23|   78.31| 78.33|  78.0|     78.01|49.33M| 0.4931869152089599|
|XPTO11|2022-02-21|   14.91| 14.99| 14.84|     14.92|14.49M| 0.5196152422706636|
|XPTO11|2022-02-22|   14.96| 15.05| 14.02|     14.02|14.43M| 0.5196152422706636|
|XPTO11|2022-02-23|   14.91| 14.99| 14.84|     14.92|14.49M| 0.5196152422706636|
+------+----------+--------+------+------+----------+------+-------------------+
```

```
#Ordenando a coluna desvio_padrão por ordem decrescente e pegando apenas a 1a linha:
df\
    .select('nome','desvio_padrão')\
    .orderBy(F.desc('desvio_padrão'))\
    .limit(1)\
    .show()
```

Output:

```
+------+------------------+
|  nome|     desvio_padrão|
+------+------------------+
|XPTO11|0.5196152422706636|
+------+------------------+
```

Answer (score -2):

Você pode fazer uma simples agregação pelo nome da empresa, por exemplo:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.groupBy('nome').agg(F.stddev('fechamento').alias('desvio_padrao')).orderBy(F.col('desvio_padrao').desc()).limit(1).show()
```